# Bibliography style in CV

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

I'm using the following  nice [LaTeX template for CV](http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/cv/). I'm getting the bibliography in the following style

```
Hyndman, R. J., M. L. King, I. Pitrun, and M. B. Billah etc
```

I want the `apacite` style. I tried the following code:

```
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

but it did not work. I'd highly appreciate if you help me to figure out this. Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that the class used in this example you're referencing to uses `biblatex`. The `apacite` package is designed for use with bibtex. I've never used this style but I found the [`biblatex-apa`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa.pdf) style which might help you.

Comment: The `cv.sty` (according to the link in the question) loads biblatex so: `\usepackage[sorting=ynt,bibstyle=authoryear-comp,labelyear=false,defernumbers=true,maxnames=20,firstinits=true, uniquename=init,dashed=false]{biblatex}`, so you probably want to comment out that line and provide instead `\usepackage[sytle=apa]{biblatex}` (as Thorsten suggests).

Comment: I should've added that `cv.sty` makes some other modifications to the default biblatex style.  I've never used `biblatex-apa`, but I suspect the changes in `cv.sty` should also be commented out. Specifically, the `\DeclareFieldFormat`, `\DeclareBibliographyDriver`, and `\renewbibmacro*`.  I think the `bibliography categories` stuff should be fine, but I guess look there first if `biblatex-apa` seems incompatible with `cv.sty`.

Comment: I'm a casual LaTeX user. It would be fine if I get any consistent bibliography style like this: `Hyndman, R. J., King, M. L.,  Pitrun, I., and Billah, M. B.  etc`. I tried the earlier code in your comment but unfortunately got the same style. I would appreciate if you suggest me any code to get the following bibliography style: `Hyndman, R. J., King, M. L.,  Pitrun, I., and Billah, M. B.  etc`. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 --- I'm afraid I have no idea what you mean by the list of names insofar as it might or might not relate to a bibliographical style (is that [not] APA?).  On a side-note, I tried (quickly) to use the biblatex-apa (4.4) with this `cv.sty` file and the results were not promising (compared, e.g., with the biblatex-chicago package).  If the bibliography format is the most important, focus on that. It would not be hard to imitate what this `cv.sty` file does 'by hand' if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load `biblatex-apa` as a package option when you load the `biblatex` package (thanks Thorsten). The problem is that the cv package you are referring to includes bibliography formatting commands (things like `\DeclareBibliographyDriver`) so you will need to manually load the `biblatex` pacakge after you load the cv package, but even then you might run into some compatibility issues.

Comment: Afaik you can't use `\bibliographystyle` in `biblatex`. The `biblatex-apa` style is designed to use with `biblatex`. So you can't use it like you mentioned above (`\bibliographystyle{biblatex-apa}`). It has to be used like this: `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}`. This is exactly what I mentioned above in my comment.

Comment: @Thorsten, thank you. I heavily edited the answer. The point I wanted to make, beyond your comment, was that the cv package is over writing portions of whatever style gets loaded.